# Rails 3.1 has_many through - recurring nightmare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some major issues with has_many through associations and could really do with some assistance.

In the context of the [Ruby On Rails guide example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), how would I go about coding a form that for a given physician would list all patients and specifically their appointment times that could then be edited. I would want to be able to edit both the patient name & their appointment date in the same form.....this is essentially the crux of the issue i'm having; editing both models in the same form and having it persist values on both.

If anyone can provide some pointers or a working example it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a problem involving a nested model form(has_many). Try this railscast for info about doing this in rails: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 Of particular interest to you should be the accepts_nested_attributes_for method.

Comment: That Railscast was my starting point and I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for but still no joy :(

Comment: I just noticed that there is an updated version of the railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised Costs money but well worth it in my opinion.